# jQuery dialog resize event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a dialog that hosts a 3rd party plugin (jqGrid). I want the `jqGrid` to autosize when the dialog is resized. I also want to have this dialog be `width: 'auto'` because there is some other content that may grow.

When the dialog resizes because of the content, I don't get the `dialogresize` event fired. Here is an example -- resizing the dialog manually causes the `dialogresize` event to fire, but clicking the button does not trigger `dialogresize`, even though the dialog resized:

http://jsfiddle.net/LfpC7/

Do you know if it's possible to catch the event when dialog resizes as a result of `width: 'auto'` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can do with jQuery UI dialogue's [`resize` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-resize).

This event is triggered when the dialog is resized. demo
Code examples

Supply a callback function to handle the resize event as an init option.

```
    $( ".selector" ).dialog({
       resize: function(event, ui) { ... }
    });
```

Bind to the resize event by type: dialogresize.

```
    $( ".selector" ).bind( "dialogresize", function(event, ui) {
      ...
    });
```